# Docker service replicated mode - How to deploy containers evenly among workers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm with 5 workers, 3 of which are managers.

I tried deploying 10 replicas for a service (using replicated mode) and expected 10 of them to be deployed evenly among 5 workers (2 instances per worker)

But all of them went to 1 single worker.

Is this the default behaviour of docker service and is there any solution to achieve my goal above?

Comment: It's been a few years now. Did you figure it out?
Perhaps you could show us some of your configuration.